# How to i display the data from tmdb api using the value or data from a different api

Tags: javascript

Im am trying to display the data for a movie using tmdb api by taking in the response from my api which only contains the id of the tmdb movie id

here is my api which has the following response.

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "title": "Demon slayer Mugen Train",
    "tmdbid": "635302"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Avengers Endgame",
    "tmdbid": "299534"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Black Widow",
    "tmdbid": "497698"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "The Suicide Squad",
    "tmdbid": "436969"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "title": "The Meg",
    "tmdbid": "345940"
  }
]
```

This is the code which i am working with

```
const container = document.querySelector('.cards-home-1 .row');
const TMDB_API_KEY = "API_KEY";
const BASE_URL = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/"

const renderPosts = async () => {

    let uri = 'http://localhost:3000/movies';
  
    const res = await fetch(uri);

    const movies = await res.json();

    const movieDetails = await fetch('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/' + 635302 + '?api_key=' + TMDB_API_KEY + '&language=en-US&append_to_response=credits');

    const movieTmdb = await movieDetails.json();
  
    let template = '';
    movies.forEach(movie => {
      template += `
      <div class="s-card col-xl-2 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-6">
      <a href="">
        <figure class="figure">
          <div class="card-img">
            <img src="${BASE_URL}${movieTmdb.backdrop_path}" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded" alt="A">
            <div class="middle">
              <a href="#" class="round-button">
                <i class="fas fa-play"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <figcaption class="figure-caption text-center"><h5>${movieTmdb.original_title}</h5></figcaption>
        </figure>
      </a>
    </div>
      `
    });
  
    container.innerHTML = template;
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => renderPosts());
```

but i dont want to initilize a value to get the response

```
const movieDetails = await fetch('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/' + ***I_want_the_id_from_my_api_here*** + '?api_key=' + TMDBAPI + '&language=en-US&append_to_response=credits');
```

Comment: if you want to display one one movie and its detail then you should pass the id in api.Or if you want movies like trending and upcoming then you should call the api of that i.e /trending

Comment: I want to display a bunch of movies based on my api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move these two lines inside the forEach loop, also replace the movieId with `movie.tmdbid` and voila you are all set.

```
const movieDetails = await fetch('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/' + movie.tmdbid + '?api_key=' + TMDB_API_KEY + '&language=en-US&append_to_response=credits');

const movieTmdb = await movieDetails.json();
```

Refer the code below:

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.cards-home-1 .row');
const TMDB_API_KEY = "API_KEY";
const BASE_URL = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/"

const renderPosts = async() => {

  let uri = 'http://localhost:3000/movies';

  const res = await fetch(uri);

  const movies = await res.json();

  let template = '';
  
  for (let movie of movies) {
    //add these two lines here \/ --line 16
    const movieDetails = await fetch('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/' + movie.tmdbid + '?api_key=' + TMDB_API_KEY + '&language=en-US&append_to_response=credits');

    const movieTmdb = await movieDetails.json();
    template += `
      <div class="s-card col-xl-2 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-6">
      <a href="">
        <figure class="figure">
          <div class="card-img">
            <img src="${BASE_URL}${movieTmdb.backdrop_path}" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded" alt="A">
            <div class="middle">
              <a href="#" class="round-button">
                <i class="fas fa-play"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <figcaption class="figure-caption text-center"><h5>${movieTmdb.original_title}</h5></figcaption>
        </figure>
      </a>
    </div>
      `
  };

  container.innerHTML = template;
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => renderPosts());
```

Comment: its throwing an error where exactly do i put there two line can you please modify my code and send the entire function cause my entire js file is a mess

Comment: @YeshwanthB, Added whole code. Let me know if you still face any issues.

Comment: Its throwing this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules`

Comment: Modified the code we need to replace the forEach loop with for loop, to use await.